# How to get a move-only type out of a STL container?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, containers, move

Let's consider an `std::unordered_set` of `std::unique_ptr<T>` as an example. Can I move an element of the set elsewhere ?

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<int>> mySet;

    mySet.insert(std::make_unique<int>(1));
    mySet.insert(std::make_unique<int>(2));
    mySet.insert(std::make_unique<int>(3));

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> myVector;

    for (auto&& element : mySet)
    {
        std::cout << *element << std::endl;
        //myVector.push_back(element); won't compile as you can only get a const ref to the key
    }
}
```

I have a very practical example of code where I would like to do this but am reduced to use a `std::shared_ptr`. Do you know of another (better ?) alternative ?

Comment: Note that this problem does not occur if `mySet` were a `std::vector` instead; it is peculiar to [node-based containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle). Also note that if you succeed in moving it, it may make other operations on that set undefined behavior since the moved-from object is no longer valid to read from, e.g., for insertion or finding, so caution must be exercised in using the container at all.

Comment: @metal I am probably doing something wrong but I am having the same compilation error with vectors only, See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51af3ac220c44619. edit: My bad, works with a `std::move`. Thanks ! The new code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95cb8a827d587723

Comment: There's a useful technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220220/efficiently-erase-a-unique-ptr-from-an-unordered-set/60220391#60220391) which is efficient, if ugly. That code is for erasing, but can be modified to move/extract instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++03, C++11, and C++14, not directly. You'd have to change the type to be something like:

```
template <class T>
struct handle {
    mutable std::unique_ptr<T> owning_ptr;
    T* observing_ptr; // enforce that observing_ptr == owning_ptr.get() on construction

    // define operator<, hash, etc. in terms of the observing ptr
};
```

With this, you can write:

```
std::unordered_set<handle<int>> mySet;
// initialize as appropriate

for (auto& elem : mySet) {
    myVector.push_back(std::move(elem.owning_ptr));        
}
mySet.clear();
```

This will still be well-defined behavior because we're not messing with any of the container internals - the observing pointer will still be valid through the end of the `clear()`, just now `myVector` owns it instead.

---

In C++17, we can do this directly and more simply with the help of [`extract()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/extract):

```
for (auto it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end();  
{
    std::cout << **it << std::endl;
    myVector.push_back(std::move(
        mySet.extract(it++).value()));
}
```

Comment: You could make the container contain a mutable tagged union-like of the smart pointer and a dumb pointer that agree on ordering, and an operation that swaps from smart to dumb while returning the smart.  The extract the smart, erase the dumb, and bob is your uncle.

Comment: @Yakk One step ahead of you :) Except made it not a union, but yeah it could be.

Comment: Should that not be `handle<int>` rather than `handle<std::unique_ptr<int>>`?

Comment: @Yakk and @Barry Thanks, I think I will go for this handy `handle` as a union ! ;)

Comment: A pair or struct is union-like.  ;)  You could also use a unique ptr with a special deleter that understands move-to default-delete as "transform to dumb pointer".