# Extracting move only type from std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set, move

I have a `std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and  I'd like to move it to a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class C {};

int main()
{
  std::set<std::unique_ptr<const C>> s;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const C>> v;
  std::move(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

This gives the following error on VS2017:

> error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Can't we make move iterators to non-const variables from a `std::set`? What could be a viable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to extract move-only elements from a set, the only possibility is to use the [`extract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) method, which was added in C++17:

```
while (!s.empty())
    v.emplace_back(std::move(s.extract(s.begin()).value()));
```

If you cannot use C++17, it is permissible to modify an element of a set (e.g. using `mutable`) *only if* you ensure that it retains the same position in the imposed ordering - that is, as long as it has the same result under your comparator when compared to all other members of the set. You can do this by providing a comparator that orders empty unique pointers before non-empty (note that the standard does not guarantee this) and erasing the modified element immediately after modifying it:

```
template<class T> struct MutableWrapper { mutable T value; };
template<class T> struct MutableWrapperCompare {
  bool operator()(MutableWrapper<T> const& lhs, MutableWrapper<T> const& rhs) {
    return lhs.value && rhs.value ? lhs.value < rhs.value : rhs.value;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::set<MutableWrapper<std::unique_ptr<const C>>, MutableWrapperCompare<std::unique_ptr<const C>>> s;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const C>> v;
  while (!s.empty())
  {
    v.emplace_back(std::move(s.begin()->value));
    s.erase(s.begin());
  }
}
```

This is however rather ugly and dangerous; you would be better off using `boost::container::set` from [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/container.html), which has the C++17 extract method ([since 1.62.0](https://github.com/boostorg/container/commit/4298d1984bd8f43f637e42b510f827309a9a13c5); it [was undocumented](https://github.com/boostorg/container/pull/52), but this is just an oversight, note the corresponding `extract` methods are documented for `map` and `multimap`).

Comment: So is there anyway that I can implement this method for my source base until the compiler I use  implements it ?

Comment: @tunc sort of, but it's ugly - see above. If at all possible I would recommend using Boost (boost::container::set, v 1.62.0 and above).

Comment: how about the `merge` method ?

Comment: @v.oddou: `merge` is also C++17

Comment: There's another approach [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810367/how-to-get-a-move-only-type-out-of-a-stl-container/39810384#39810384), which is a little less dangerous, but still not ideal.